# React Native TCP, Invariant Violation : Native module cannot be null

Tags: sockets, react-native, tcp, react-native-ios

I have a problem only on iOS (working on Android) in React Native project with [react-native-tcp](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp) plugin.

[iOS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6L5.jpg)

Does anyone ever had this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: did you run react-native link react-native-tcp?

Comment: I had to unlink before and now it works, thank you